# Accepting User Input for Getter Class in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, getter

Java newbie here, I have one of those assignments where I need to write a class for creating student objects and then also write a driver.

I have all of the requirements done, except I am having trouble with this one - "Write method getTestScore that accepts test number and returns appropriate score."

I believe I've written the class correctly, but I am having trouble writing the code for the driver.

After the prompt for the user to enter the test number, it isn't returning anything and the program terminates insted of returning appropriate score .

Help is very appreciated!

Here is the class:

```
public class Student
{ 
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private String homeAddress, schoolAddress;
    private int testScore1, testScore2, testScore3;

    //Constructors
    public Student()
    {
        firstName = "None";
        lastName = "None";
        homeAddress = "None";
        schoolAddress = "None";
        testScore1 = 0;
        testScore2 = 0;
        testScore3 = 0;
    }

    public Student(String first, String last, String home, String school, int score1, int score2, int score3)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        homeAddress = home;
        schoolAddress = school;
        testScore1 = score1;
        testScore2 = score2;
        testScore3 = score3;
    }

    //Setter for test scores
    public void setTestScore(int testNum, int score)
    {
        if (testNum == 1)
            testScore1 = score;
        else
            if (testNum == 2)
                testScore2 = score;
            else
              if (testNum == 3)
                testScore3 = score;
              else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(testNum + " is out of range");
        }
    //Getter for test scores
    public int getTestScore(int testNum2)
    {
        if (testNum2 == 1)
            return testScore1;
        else
            if (testNum2 == 2)
                return testScore2;
            else
              if (testNum2 == 3)
                return testScore3;
              else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(testNum2 + " is out of range");
        }
    //Calculates average for each student
    public int getAverage()
    {
        int average = (testScore1 + testScore2 + testScore3)/3;
        return average;
    }
    //Returns a description of this Student object
    public String toString()
    {
        String result;

        result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
        result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
        result += "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress + "\n";
        result += "Test Score 1:\n" + testScore1 + "\n";
        result += "Test Score 2:\n" + testScore2 + "\n";
        result += "Test Score 3:\n" + testScore3 + "\n";
        result += "Average Test Score:\n" + ((testScore1+testScore2+testScore3)/3);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is the driver:

```
package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentBody {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    //Create student objects
    {
        Student snm24 = new Student("Sarah", "M", "18 79th Street", "5000 Forbes Ave.", 95, 80, 63);
        Student adk28 = new Student("Andrew", "K", "16 Collins Ave.", "16401 NW 37th Ave.", 90, 82, 76);

        //Get average for snm24
        snm24.getAverage();
        System.out.println("snm24 average initial: " + snm24.getAverage());

        //Set new test score for test 3 for snm24 and see new average
        snm24.setTestScore(3, 68);
        System.out.println("snm24 average after adjustment: " +snm24.getAverage());

        //Get test score for adk28
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which test score are you looking for?:");
        int testNum2 = scan.nextInt();
        adk28.getTestScore(testNum2);
    }
}
```

Comment: this here adk28.getTestScore(testNum2);

Answer (score 1):

> *it isn't returning anything and the program terminates. Help is very appreciated!*

this here>

```
adk28.getTestScore(testNum2);
```

the returned value is getting lost.. do something with that, print it, assign it to a variable:

```
int result =  adk28.getTestScore(testNum2);
```

Comment: Wow, that's a quick fix. 

Comment: told you I was a newbie :X Thanks so much for the helpful and quick response!